# Odd behavior extending Django tutorial with urlpatterns

Tags: django

Building a new django site following the first app tutorial. Created polls ok and site.urls.py

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path("polls/", include("polls.urls")),
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
]
```

All is well and http://localhost:8000/polls/ gives the proper response "Hello World..."

Now I run `python manage.py startapp brollysaas` and the folders get created

site.urls is now

```py
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path("polls/", include("polls.urls")),
    path("brolly/", include("brollysaas.urls")),
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
]
```

I am getting

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'brollysaas.urls'

Everything else is the same as polls including settings.  So I cannot figure out the error or remedy.

Comment: Do you have a `urls.py` in the new app folder?

Comment: I did and double chrvked spelling etc. I created a new one with slightly different name and that worked.  Still no idea why but not a road block.

Answer (score 0):

Set an `app_name` attribute in the `URLconf` module of app `brollysaas` so that you can use [**URL namespaces** <sup>[django-docs]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/http/urls/#url-namespaces-and-included-urlconfs) like you did:

```
# brollysaas urls.py
app_name = "brollysaas" # <—- now you can use the namespace "brollysaas" in django::urls::include().
```

Now this will run correctly:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path("polls/", include("polls.urls")),
    path("brolly/", include("brollysaas.urls")), # <—- the namespace "brollysaas" now exists.
    path("admin/", admin.site.urls),
]
```

Note: the `app_name` attribute must be at the same level as the `urlpatterns` attribute.